# Unable to retrieve querystring data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my bus service MVC project I need to be able to display a bus route stops only when i go to the route table. I have this ActionLink sending the querystring and the page to the route table: `@Html.ActionLink("Route Stops", "index", "snRouteStops", new { id=item.busRouteCode}, null)`
But when I get to my bus route stops controller I need it to throw me back to the route lists if there isn't one selected. This part works fine but when I click a route to view the stops nothing happens. Here is my code in the actionResult of the busRouteStops controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string busRouteCode = "";

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["busRouteCode"]))
            {
                if (Request.Cookies["busRouteCode"] == null)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "snBusRoutes");
                }
                else
                {
                    busRouteCode = Request.Cookies["busRouteCode"].ToString();                    
                }    
            }
            else
            {
                busRouteCode = Request.QueryString["busRouteCode"].ToString();            

            }
             var routeStops = db.routeStops.Include(r => r.busRoute).Where(r => r.busRouteCode == busRouteCode).Include(r => r.busStop);
        return View(routeStops.ToList());
    }
        }
```

Comment: Could you share also a view code?

Comment: which view would you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are looking for a query string with the name `busRouteCode`, but your action link is not setup to provide a query string with that name.  Your action link -

```
@Html.ActionLink("Route Stops", "index", "snRouteStops", new { id=item.busRouteCode}, null)
```

is configured to send the `busRouteCode` as a parameter with the name id.  That means that the URL will look like this:

`/snRouteStops/Index?id=myBusRouteCode`

Thus, there is no query string with the name `busRouteCode`

You can do a few things to clean this up.

1. Standard routing in MVC is configured to use /Controller/Action/id.  You can update your index action to be aware that an Id is coming by updating the action method.

---

//appears id is a string based on your code

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            string busRouteCode = "";

            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                if (Request.Cookies["busRouteCode"] == null)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "snBusRoutes");
                }
                else
                {
                    busRouteCode = Request.Cookies["busRouteCode"].ToString();                    
                }    
            }
            else
            {
                busRouteCode = id;            

            }
             var routeStops = db.routeStops.Include(r => r.busRoute).Where(r => r.busRouteCode == busRouteCode).Include(r => r.busStop);
        return View(routeStops.ToList());
    }
        }
```

---

2. Change your action link to send the busRouteCode as a parameter named busRouteCode.

`@Html.ActionLink("Route Stops", "index", "snRouteStops", new { busRouteCode=item.busRouteCode}, null)`

This will generate a link that looks like:

`/snRouteStops/Index?busRouteCode=myBusRouteCodeValue`

However you proceed, you should not really ever have to use Request.QueryString[] in your MVC controller actions.  By configuring your action method to be looking for those query string values(like I did in example one), you can now get strongly typed parameters in your action methods as opposed to the string values in the QueryString[] dictionary. This is especially helpful when expecting an integer as a query string value for instance.  The model binder will take care of ensuring that query string value is actually an integer and not a string.

Comment: thanks so much. doing the strong typed parameter works.

Answer (score 1):

This code `{id=item.busRouteCode}` generates query like that:
http://snRouteStops/Index?id=somedata
where somedata = item.busRouteCode.
Try to look for id in query string or just add id to action params, like that:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
```

Comment: I seem to recall doing this before do i need to change the busRouteCodes to just id? in the rest of the actionResult?

Comment: Yes, query string will contain id as a key and busRouteCode as a value.  So this code will return query string with key=id. Request.QueryString["id"]

Comment: You can also change this code: new { id=item.busRouteCode} to this one new { busRouteCode=item.busRouteCode}. Then you'll have busRouteCode as a key in query string